# Layout Page not rendering Some Pages Asp.net MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, asp.net-mvc-5

i am trying to develop MVC5 applicaiton. i am facing a problem. i have set a layout page placed in shared folder. Home pages of all controls are working properly.

[image]

but other pages are not showing in proper way.

I have attached a sample page Details

[image]

[image]

[image]

I checked css is also showing in source but page is not displaying in proper way

[image]

Thanks in advance. i am new in MVC

Answer (score 1):

If you open your browser's Developer Toolbar and review the network tab you should be able to see if your pages are returning 404 for the files.  When your browser is open press F12 and the toolbars should open.

It looks to me like your references to your local/application based stylesheets/javascript are missing the tilde symbol `~` at the beginning which means in ASP.NET the server-side application root.

For example `~/Content/bootstrap.css` would be translated to the URL of the bootstrap.css file that's in the application's root.

You can drag and drop the bootstrap.css file in your content file into the _layout.cshtml file to see the correct path for the href attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Put the sympole ~ before the link of css path

Comment: Not that your answer not enough to solve OP's problem. But you may want to explain your solution.